# Different embedding checksums after encoding with SentenceTransformers?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, sentence-transformers

I am calculating some embeddings with SentenceTransformers Library. However, I get different results when encoding the sentences and calculating their embeddings when checking the sum of their values. For instance:

In:

```
RANDOM_SEED = 42
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


transformer_models = [
    'M-CLIP/M-BERT-Distil-40', 
                     ]

sentences = df['content'].tolist()


for transformer_model in tqdm(transformer_models, desc="Transformer Models"):
    tqdm.write(f"Processing with Transformer Model: {transformer_model}")
    model = SentenceTransformer(transformer_model)
    embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
    print(f"Embeddings Checksum for {transformer_model}:", np.sum(embeddings))
```

Out:

```
Embeddings Checksum for M-CLIP/M-BERT-Distil-40: 1105.9185
```

Or

```
Embeddings Checksum for M-CLIP/M-BERT-Distil-40: 1113.5422
```

I noticed this situation happens when I restart and clear the output of the jupyter notebook, and then re-run the full notebook. Any idea of how to fix this issue?

Alternative I tried to set after and before the embeddings calculation the reandom seeds:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

RANDOM_SEED = 42

# Setting seeds
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

# Ensuring PyTorch determinism
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

transformer_models = ['M-CLIP/M-BERT-Distil-40']

sentences = df['content'].tolist()

for transformer_model in tqdm(transformer_models, desc="Transformer Models"):
    # Set the seed again right before loading the model
    np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
    random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
    tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
    torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

    tqdm.write(f"Processing with Transformer Model: {transformer_model}")
    model = SentenceTransformer(transformer_model, device='cpu')  # Force to use CPU

    embeddings = model.encode(sentences, show_progress_bar=False)  # Disable progress bar and parallel tokenization
    print(f"Embeddings Checksum for {transformer_model}:", np.sum(embeddings))
```

However I am getting the same inconsistent behavior.

**UPDATE**

What I tried now, and seem to work is that now I store all the calculated embeddings in files. However, I find weird that when doing this I get different results. Does anyone has experience this before?

Comment: A few questions to start off with, (a) in regards to the inconsistency, is it varying all the time, or does it alternate between a few different values consistently? (b) the data that you are using `df['contents']`, can you share some information where this comes from and what it is? (c) this sentence transformer is a multi-lingual model so assuming you have a few or many different languages, are you certain that the representation of all characters is consistent and accurate when you read data? (d) do you also notice this inconsistency in a python file, or just the notebooks?

Comment: Can you share us your data/list of sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the `.apply` method instead of `.encode` --> for me, that worked for a similar application which helped to resolve the reproducibility issue.

It seems to be an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2401) faced by many people. You can follow this issue for more information on different embeddings depending on different batch sizes/other settings and their solutions. [different precision settings, specifying/ensuring consistent tokenization and padding of the input, etc.]